# GPEdit Powershell command to block tcp ports

Tags: powershell, windows-firewall

I'm trying to block TCP ports 445 and 139 on a domain computer, via local Group policy. To manually do this, I can go into

- GPEdit
- Computer Configuration
- Windows Settings
- Security Settings
- Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security
- Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security - Local Group Policy Object
- Open the Outbound rules

From there, create a new rule with the following settings: Port>TCP>445, 139>Block>Apply rule to domain, private, and public firewall>Name appropriately, and finish. I'd like to do this in Powershell to better implement the update.

I can't seem to figure out how to get to the local group policy object in Powershell, and have tried multiple ways to get the NetGPO to connect with no avail.

```
$Session=Open-NetGPO -Computername <COMPUTERNAME> 
Open-NetGPOGroup
New-NetFirewallRule -GpoSession $Session -DisplayName "Block Outbound TCP Port 445, 139" -Direction Outbound -LocalPort 445,139 -Protocol TCP -Action Block
```

Errors:

```
*Open-NetGPO : The parameter is incorrect. 
At line:1 char:13
+ $GpoSession=Open-NetGPO 042staffii02w10
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (MSFT_NetGPO:root/standardcimv2/MSFT_NetGPO) [Open-NetGPO], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error 87,Open-NetGPO
 
Open-NetGPOGroup : The term 'Open-NetGPOGroup' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:2 char:1
+ Open-NetGPOGroup
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Open-NetGPOGroup:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 
New-NetFirewallRule : The parameter is incorrect. 
At line:3 char:1
+ New-NetFirewallRule -GPOSession $GpoSession -DisplayName "Block Outbo ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (MSFT_NetFirewallRule:root/standardcimv2/MSFT_NetFirewallRule) [New-NetFirewallRule], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error 87,New-NetFirewallRule
 
New-NetFirewallRule : The parameter is incorrect. 
At line:4 char:1
+ New-NetFirewallRule -GPOSession $GpoSession -DisplayName "Block Outbo ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (MSFT_NetFirewallRule:root/standardcimv2/MSFT_NetFirewallRule) [New-NetFirewallRule], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error 87,New-NetFirewallRule*
```

I've also tried setting the PolicyStore to the computername to get it to connect to the local policy. `$Session=Open-NetGPO -PolicyStore <COMPUTERNAME>\'Windows Firewall'`
Error:

```
Open-NetGPO : The system cannot find the file specified. 
At line:1 char:13
+ $GpoSession=Open-NetGPO -PolicyStore <COMPUTERNAME>\'Windows Firewal ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (MSFT_NetGPO:root/sta
```

Can anyone please provide any pointers on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggestions from Situ, I created a new OU in Group Policy and added the policies directly into a new GPO.

Comment: great to hear that, I hope the problem could be resolved. In case my answers were helpful I would appreciate it if you could upvote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A use a lot powershell to deploy GPO, to deploy a firewall rule I do:

```
$GpoName = '[FW] Block 445,139/TCP'

New-GPO -Name $GpoName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$GpoSessionName = Open-NetGPO –PolicyStore ("{0}\{1}" -f $env:USERDNSDOMAIN,$GpoName)
New-NetFirewallRule -Enabled True -Profile Any -ErrorAction Continue -GPOSession $GpoSessionName -PolicyStore $GpoName -DisplayName '[GPO] Block Outbound TCP Port 445, 139' -Direction Outbound -LocalPort @(445,139) -Protocol TCP -Action Block
Save-NetGPO -GPOSession $GpoSessionName
```

to avoid all these complex tasks, I have made a basic function (https://github.com/1mm0rt41PC/SecureDomain/blob/main/Function_FWRule.ps1):

```
function FWRule( $param )
{
    $GpoName_raw = $param['GpoName']
    $GpoName = $param['GpoName'] -replace '\] \[', ']['
    $param.remove('GpoName')
    New-GPO -Name $GpoName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $GpoSessionName = Open-NetGPO –PolicyStore ("{0}\{1}" -f $env:USERDNSDOMAIN,$GpoName)
    $param['GPOSession']  = $GpoSessionName;
    $param['PolicyStore'] = $GpoName;
    $param['DisplayName'] = ("[GPO] {0}" -f $GpoName_raw) -Replace '\] \[', '][';
    $param.remove('Name')
    New-NetFirewallRule -Enabled True -Profile Any -ErrorAction Continue @param
    Save-NetGPO -GPOSession $GpoSessionName
}
```

Then I use it like this:

```
FWRule @{
    GpoName='[FW] Block 445,139/TCP';
    Action='Block'; Direction='Inbound'; Name='Block 139,445/TCP';
    Protocol='TCP';
    RemotePort=@('139','445')
}
```

You can find many examples of my GPO deployement via powershell on my git https://github.com/1mm0rt41PC/SecureDomain/blob/main/DC.ps1

Using the Windows firewall is a very good idea, It can give you a zerotrust security.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you try to use local GPO for this task? You could easily use the gpmc and create a gpo that is stored in AD. In this case, you centrally see what is configured and the settings are backed up in sysvol. You can centrally apply new settings or disable the rules and apply the settings to other machines as well.

Comment: Settings within our Group Policy are in place that override what I'm trying to do within the firewall directly. Additionally, this update is temporary and needs to be done on 1-5 PCs at a time. I was able to confirm that the local group policy entry overrides the domain wide policy when done using the manual update. If possible, I'd like to avoid creating another OU in our domain Group Policy.

Comment: Based on my understanding local group policies are read first and then overwritten by Site, Domain and OU policies. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc785665(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN You could create a central GPO and apply the security filtering to just the 5 servers. Place the GPO as near as you can to the servers. As long as there are no enforcement in place you should be fine. What do you exactly mean with "manual update"?

Comment: What you could use as a tool to export, import or deploy local GPOs is LGPO.exe https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-security-baselines/lgpo-exe-local-group-policy-object-utility-v1-0/ba-p/701045  However I still guess that the local entries get overritten by domain gpos.

Comment: By manual edit, I mean that I can manually go into local group policy to make the update and it works.

Comment: I was able to create an OU in our GP Management that has no inheritance and running a gpupdate/force should have removed all policies. I have successfully run 'new-netfirewallrule -DisplayName "Block TCP ports" -direction outbound -localport 445,139 -protocol TCP -action Block
new-netfirewallrule -DisplayName "Block UDP ports" -direction outbound -localport 137,138 -protocol TCP -action Block'

This provides 0 errors, and the block is listed in the Firewall. However TCP port 445 is still listening per netstat -ab. It shows that it can not obtain ownership information below the status.

Comment: sure netstat can still listen on port 445 because the service is still running, but the firewall will block the access from external machines. Try to access the port via test-netconnection -ComputerName <FQDN of blocked host> -port 445 from another machine. It should be blocked if the gpo is setup correctly and processed (GPOupdate /force can help or a reboot). You should also see your success (blocked packets) in local firewall txt log. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/166875/how-do-i-access-a-firewall-log-windows-10-w-windows-defender